# How to give InkResponse a rectangular highlight?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to make the [InkResponse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html) Widget to have a rectangular highlight on click, How could i do so?

[image]

i have tried to make ***highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle*** but in vain.

**this Is the code:**

```dart
   Container(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            height: 11.h,
            width: 10.h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1.w)),
              color: const Color(accentColor),
            ),
            child: InkResponse(
              highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle,

              highlightColor: const Color(greyColor),

              onTap: () async {},
              // bottom sheet button icon
              child: BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
                buildWhen: (previousState, currentState) =>
                    previousState != currentState,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Icon(
                    state is OpenBottomSheet ? Icons.save : Icons.add,
                    color: const Color(whiteColor),
                    size: 9.h,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `highlightShape` parameter of `InkResponse` like `highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle,`.

```dart
InkResponse(
        highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle, //<-  shape
        highlightColor: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(.5),
        containedInkWell: true, //<- this will make sure to keep everything within Widget.
        onTap: () {
          print('Tapped');
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("BTN"),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Also, you can try [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html).
TO know more about [InkResponse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html)

Comment: you can  also use `containedInkWell: true,`

Comment: it does not work, i attached the code in my question, could you see it again please? @Yessin Sheikh

Comment: `BoxShape.rectangle` will set the full size of the button and make it rectangle, are you also trying to make the splash rectangular shape?

Comment: i have attached the button on my question,too. 
all what i need to make a highlight around the button as a rectangular border. @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: You are having `splash` beyond the size, it happens on small-sized widget.  Use `containedInkWell: true, it will force keeping inside the widget.

Answer (score 0):

While both can be customized, it's easier to:

- Use `InkWell` for a rectangular ripple effect.
- Use `InkResponse` for a circular ripple effect.